# Represent a colored polygon in ggplot2

Tags: plot, polygon, spatstat

I am using the statspat package because I am working on spatial patterns.
I would like to do in ggplot and with colors instead of numbers (because it is not too readable),
the following graph, produced with the plot.quadratest function: [Polygone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9QwH.png)

The numbers that interest me for the intensity of the colors are those at the bottom of each box.

The test object contains the following data:
[Test object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkxdQ.png)

I have looked at the help of the function, as well as the code of the function but I still cannot manage it.

Ideally I would like my final figure to look like this (maybe not with the same colors haha):

[Final object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmFOz.png)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide a reproducible example in the future.
The package `reprex` may be very helpful.

To use `ggplot2` for this my best bet would be to convert
`spatstat` objects to `sf` and do the plotting that way,
but it may take some time. If you are willing to use base
graphics and spatstat you could do something like:

```r
library(spatstat)
# Data (using a built-in dataset):
X <- unmark(chorley)
plot(X, main = "")
```

[image]

```r
# Test:
test <- quadrat.test(X, nx = 4)
# Default plot:
plot(test, main = "")
```

[image]

```r
# Extract the the `quadratcount` object (regions with observed counts):
counts <- attr(test, "quadratcount")
# Convert to `tess` (raw regions with no numbers)
regions <- as.tess(counts)
# Add residuals as marks to the tessellation:
marks(regions) <- test$residuals
# Plot regions with marks as colors:
plot(regions, do.col = TRUE, main = "")
```

[image]